# OpenGL PBuffer multi-sampling with texture as target (anti-aliasing)

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, multisampling

Is it possible to have PBuffer multi-sampling with texture as target?

Yes I'm aware this is old technology but at this point I need to improve smoothness of drawn shapes like rectangles and circles.

I need that to avoid rewriting huge part of application (no enough time for that) which is using PBuffer and to improve drawn shapes.

Comment: I really want to say no because the ability to use multisampled textures is a DX10 feature, but there _may_ be some obscure extension from AMD or NV that makes this possible. The real problem is how you do the multisample anti-aliasing resolve, in core GL you have to call `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` to do that, and well that sort of defeats the purpose of a PBuffer.

Comment: Multisampled textures also exists in openGL. GL_TEXTURE2D_MULTISAMPLE adn they can be used in FBO.
I've edited question to explain why i need that.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant by DX10 feature. DX10 is roughly equivalent to OpenGL 3.x, multisampled textures were first introduced to DX10 and then later made core in GL3. So in terms of hardware/driver generation, saying "DX10 feature" means much newer than PBuffers ;)